# If Statement in Timber/Twig not working for me

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

So if I have a `{% if post.product_status != 'In Stock' or 'In Transit' %}` {# execute my code #} `{% endif %}` what would this not be working is there something wrong with me using the `or` operator? What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement will always return `true` because of `In Transit` - it is non-empty string.

You may test it

```
{% if 'In Transit' %}
    // Will be executed
{% endif %}

{% if false or 'In Transit' %}
    // Will be executed because one of condition is true
{% endif %}

{% if post.product_status != 'In Stock' or post.product_status != 'In Transit' %}
    // Will be executed. Why? Even if your status is not 'In Stock' second part of condition will return true
{% endif %}

{% if post.product_status != 'In Stock' and post.product_status != 'In Transit' %}
    // Will NOT be executed if status is 'In Stock' or 'In Transit'. Both conditions are false now
{% endif %}
```

This condition became quite unreadable so it is better to change it to. Let's check does our status value present in an array of excluded statusses

```
{% set excluded = [ 'In Stock', 'In Transit', 'Any New Status Here' ] %}

{% if post.product_status not in excluded %}
    // Code to execute
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank-you once again for such a simple a good working answer!